# Ubuntu 14.04: Fine tuning Touchpad for ThinkPad S431

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, thinkpad

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad S431. The touchpad is very bumpy, tricky to use. Slides down with a small touch, sometimes jerks erratically. I have tried to modify the settings in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` file as below --

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "JumpyCursorThreshold" "250"
    Option "VertResolution" "100"
#   Option "HorizResolution" "65"
#   Option "MinSpeed" "1"
#   Option "MaxSpeed" "1"
#   Option "AccelerationProfile" "1"
#   Option "AdaptiveDeceleration" "8"
#   Option "ConstantDeceleration" "1"
#   Option "VelocityScale" "128"
    Option "HorizHysteresis" "150"
    Option "VertHysteresis" "150"
EndSection
```

There are lots of options here, does anyone know how to get a fine-tuned values for the above options (for ThinkPad S431)? The Hysteresis values seems to alleviate the problem a little bit, but failed to get a perfect result.

**EDIT:**

According to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1042069) for ThinkPad X230 (+X230t), I set these values and quite good for now --

```
Option "VertResolution" "100"
Option "HorizResolution" "65"
Option "MinSpeed" "1"
Option "MaxSpeed" "1"
Option "AccelerationProfile" "2"
Option "AdaptiveDeceleration" "16"
Option "ConstantDeceleration" "16"
Option "VelocityScale" "32"
Option "HorizHysteresis" "50"
Option "VertHysteresis" "50"
```

and then you need to increase the cursor speed manually from the Unity mouse settings.

But I am still looking for a fully functional (possibly with all the gestures) and a fine-tuned touchpad settings for S431.

Further help is appreciated.